# onSnapshot in onAuthStateChanged returns wrong value

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Sometimes when i update current user (for example, adding new follow) onSnapshot returns wrong user (user that i follow and not updated current), though when refreshing the page it gets back to proper user. It only happens between my own accounts (so, i guess it takes cashed user data). I'm new to react and firebase and can't get an idea of what is happening.

Here's my function where i listen to user updates:

(This is the only place where i set user.)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe;
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
        unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
          console.log(user.uid);
          console.log(doc.data().uid);
          setUserState(doc.data());
        });
      } else {
        setUserState(false);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      if (unsubscribe) {
        unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

This is where followers updated:

```
async function updateFollow(db, follower, followee){
  const followerRef = doc(db, "users", follower.uid);
  const followerSnap = await getDoc(followerRef);
  const followerData = followerSnap.data();

  const followeeRef = doc(db, "users", followee.uid);

  if (followerData.following && followerData.following.includes(followee.profileName)){
    await updateDoc(followerRef, {
      following: arrayRemove(followee.profileName)
    })
    await updateDoc(followeeRef, {
      followers: arrayRemove(follower.profileName)
    })
  } else{
    await updateDoc(followerRef, {
      following: arrayUnion(followee.profileName)
    })
    await updateDoc(followeeRef, {
      followers: arrayUnion(follower.profileName)
    })
  }
}
```

My console.logs are equal, but react console shows different values.
So, first console.log shows that getAuth() keeps proper user (which is actually logged in), but somehow doc.data() is another one.

And yes, document name is the same as uid field.

I guess, useEffect needs some dependency, cause after refreshing the page it shows actual user? But still, how does onSnapshot returns another one?

Comment: You never unsubscribe from `onSnapshot`

Comment: You still never unsubscribe from `onSnapshot`

Comment: updated the code i use

Answer (score 1):

The `onSnapshot()` function returns an `unsubscribe` function that you can call to stop listening for changes. However, in your code, you are assigning the `unsubscribe` function to a variable called `snapshot`, and then calling it immediately. This means that you are not actually listening for changes, but just fetching the data once and then detaching the listener.

To fix this, you need to store the `unsubscribe` function in a variable and call it only when you want to stop listening, such as in the cleanup function of your `useEffect` hook.

You can also use the `includeMetadataChanges` option when calling the `onSnapshot()` function to receive events when only the metadata changes, such as the document's sync state.

For example:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe;
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, { includeMetadataChanges: true }, (doc) => {
        console.log(user.uid);
        console.log(doc.data().uid);
        setUserState(doc.data());
      });
    } else {
      setUserState(false);
    }
  });
  return () => {
    if (unsubscribe) {
      unsubscribe();
    }
  };
}, []);
```

And then, you need to call `signOut()` in your logout function. The `signOut()` method will sign out the current user and trigger the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener, which will then set the user state to false, for example:

```
const logout = () => {
  signOut(auth)
    .then(() => {})
    .catch((error) => {});
};
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's still changes user

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of the Firebase SDK, which may have some bugs or inconsistencies with the `onSnapshot()` function? You can try updating your SDK to the latest version and see if that solves your problem. Or I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: includeMetadataChanges seem to work and it doesn't switch user to another, but now it doesn't update user state with false when i logging out, only when refreshing the page

Comment: Are you calling `signOut()` on the Firebase auth instance in your `signout` function?

Comment: Yes, and i checked with `isUserSignedIn()` it shows - false, but `onAuthStateChanged` still gets user, only when i refresh it sets user to false

Comment: Another possible reason is that you are using a different Firebase auth instance or app than the one that you are listening to in your `useEffect()` hook. For example, if you are using `getAuth()` to sign out the user, but you are using `getAuth(app)` to listen to the auth state changes, where app is a different Firebase app than the default one, then you may not get the expected behavior. I updated my answer.

Comment: they're both with empty parenthesis

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue with the user state not updating on logout? If so, you may need to check if there are any other factors that may interfere with the auth state changes, such as network issues, browser settings, or conflicting code. You can also try to debug your code by adding some console logs or breakpoints to see where the problem occurs. You can also use the Firebase emulator suite to test your app locally and simulate different scenarios.

Comment: Yeap, still the same. Interesting thing is that if i remove `includeMetadataChanges` it logs out properly. Thanks for your time. I guess, i should dive into it tomorrow with a fresh head.

Comment: please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes. I hope you can find a solution to your issue soon. Have a good day.